# Find total number of subsets in O(N*M)

Tags: algorithm

I have come across recently an algorithm question as below.

There are two arrays of size 'N'.
Find the algorithm to choose subsets of elements such that the absolute difference between sum of Array1 and sum of Array2 should be <= 'M' ( where M is a constant number).

```
Eg:

    Array1 -> 1,2
    Array2 -> 4,5

    M =2

Total number of subsets are '6'

The subsets are like below

( sum of array1, sum of array2 )

(0,0) -> no numbers selected 
(1,0) -> selecting 1 from array1, selecting none from array2
(2,0) -> selecting 2 from array1, selecting none from array2
(2,4) -> selecting 2 from array1, selecting 4 from array2
(3,4) -> selecting 1,2 from array1, selecting 4 from array2
(3,5) -> selecting 1,2 from array1, selecting 5 from array2
```

The complexity of the algorithm should be O(N*M)

Thanks in advance

Comment: but those are not permutations (the sum of a permutation will always be the same) - you are talking about subsets

Comment: sorry my mistake, i meant choosing subsets from array1 & array2, let me update the same

Comment: This is known as the optimisation version of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)

Comment: as Peter said this should be not to hard using dynamic programming approaches